# Using a for-loop to print numbers

Tags: java, for-loop

I'm trying to write a program that prints all numbers from 0 to 1,000 where the number mod 5 = 3. This is what I have so far

```
public class NewMain {
public static void modNumbers(int i)
{

}

public static void main(String[] args) {

    for(int i = 0; i > 1000; i++)
    {
        if(i%5 = 3)
        {
        System.out.println(i);
        }
    }

 }
}
```

I'm not getting any output, so I know I'm doing something wrong. Should I have a return type in the method?

Comment: you probably want a double equals, `==` in your `if` along with the other corrections

Comment: Simple syntax mistakes.. > to < and = to == or even ===

Comment: Does that even compile? It should be if(i%5 == 3).

Comment: Post the answer that helped in solving your problem and mark it as solved.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Change it from:

```
for (int i = 0; i > 1000; i++)
```

to

```
for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
```

Essentially, the loop never begins because the loop invariant is false (as i is less than 1000), and your print statement is never reached because the loop never initializes.

Additionally, as WTP mentioned, use == for numeric comparisons (an important note is that you use string1.equals(string2) or compareTo with Strings, just for your future reference).

Answer (score 5):

`for(int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)`

Answer (score 5):

Here's what you have to do:

1. Change `i > 1000` to `i <= 1000` as `i` starts with 0 and increments up to 1000.
2. Change `i%5 = 3` to `i%5 == 3` as the first is doing an assignment while the second is comparing for equality.

Answer (score 3):

```
if(i%5 == 3)
```

single = is for assignment

Answer (score 2):

This:

```
if(i%5 = 3)
```

Has to be this:

```
if(i%5 == 3)
```

You are trying to set something instead of comparing it.

Answer (score 0):

Another little detail:

```
i%5 = 3
```

should be

```
i%5 == 3
```

Answer (score 0):

Need to change the > in your for statement to a <   and also the = in your if statement is an assignment operator.  Use a comparative operator == or === ...  Hope this helps.  :)

Comment: FYI `===` doesn't exist in java

Answer (score 0):

for (int i = 0; i **<** 1000; i++)

Answer (score 0):

You have two problems:

1.

```
for(int i = 0; i > 1000; i++)
```

The for loop only starts when i is greater than 1000, but the initial value for i is less than one thousand.  The code will not work.

2.

```
if(i%5 = 3)
```

You need this to have two equal signs so that it becomes a statement that returns a true or false value.  Your code would look like this after making the corrections:

```
for(int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
{
    if(i%5 == 3)
    {
    System.out.println(i);
    }
}
```